# Getting a ScrollViewers maximum scroll values?

Tags: c#, silverlight, scrollviewer

I'm trying to get the maximum amount a scrollviewer can scroll in the vertical and horizontal direction but I need to be doing this in a layout updated callback. This is what I'm currently doing:

```
        viewer.ScrollToRight( );
        doublehmax = viewer.HorizontalOffset;

        viewer.ScrollToBottom( );
        double vmax = viewer.VerticalOffset;
```

But this casues an error: "Unhandled Error in Silverlight 2 Application Layout cycle detected.  Layout could not complete."

Is there a way I can get the max horizontal and vertical offsets of the scroll view area reliably even after window resizes and the like?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

use [`ScrollableWidth`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.scrollablewidth%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) and [`Scrollableheight`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.scrollableheight%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)

Comment: The scrollViewer.Template.FindName function does not exist, FindName is not a member of Template..

Comment: look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworktemplate.aspx)

Comment: [How to reference template part](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/977972b2-b250-4607-97b4-6fca415b228e)

Comment: this applies to UWP folks btw

Comment: Msdn is vague but pretty sure those are max offset + viewport size. You only scroll until the edge is visible not to the edge

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is the ExtentWidth and ExtentHeight, right?  You want the max size of what's inside the ScrollViewer.

Comment: Yes, I said so in my post.  That should define how much the scrollviewers can scroll.

Comment: look at [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/933a696b-076f-4b74-92be-4737e74b732c)

Comment: consider a scrollviewer`s width is 500 and it's content width is 1000 in this case ExtentWidth value is 1000 but the maximum value of Scroll bar is (the size to scroll + width of scrollbar)=517

Answer (score 1):

To get max offset you need to check the `ScrollViewer`'s `ScrollBar`.

`ExtentWidth` and `ScrollableWidth` is not what you want, they include the `ScrollViewer`'s `ViewportWidth` (same with height).

Here's a `ScrollViewer` extension method to get a `ScrollBar` reference (because it's part of `ScrollViewer`'s template):

```
public static ScrollBar GetScrollBar(this ScrollViewer sv, Orientation orientation) {
            if(orientation == Orientation.Vertical) {
                return sv.Template.FindName("PART_VerticalScrollBar", sv) as ScrollBar;
            }
            return sv.Template.FindName("PART_HorizontalScrollBar", sv) as ScrollBar;
        }
```

Then to get the maximum:

```
var hScrollBar = viewer.GetScrollBar(Orientation.Horizontal);
double maxOffset = hScrollBar.Maximum;
```

(This is w/ WPF not Silverlight but googling landed me here so not sure if Template names are the same but you should get the idea)